# Is it wrong to favour integration testing over unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

We're running a project on which we started adopting test-driven design long after the development was started.

We have both unit tests and integration tests. Integration tests are run on a real database, initialized in a known state before the tests are run.

As we write tests, we start noticing than even for classes that could be tested in the "standard way", in isolation & with mock objects, it has actually become faster, and cleaner (read: shorter & easier to understand code) to just use real objects/services directly talking to the database, rather than cluttering the test class with complicated mock objects setup.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using real objects/services, then you don't know why your tests failed. E.g. you changed something in service implementation, or renamed database field, or there your network is down - you have 50 failed "unit" tests. Also you can't do test-driven development in this case, because dependencies which will be required by class you are testing should be implemented before you writing test. Can you foresee which API will be required by consumers of your service? That will lead to less usable API and code which not used at all (parameters, methods, etc).

If your tests take a lot of efforts to arrange mocks, then:

- tests should be short and simple
- don't verify what other tests already verified
- dependencies should be easy to interact with
- try to follow Single Responsibility Principle for your classes (both dependencies and sut)
- try to follow [Tell Don't Ask Principle](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) - instead of asking many questions to dependency, tell it what you want

Comment: Thanks for your opinion on this one. By *faster*, I meant *faster to write*, obviously not *faster to execute*, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Benjamin if you have to do big arrange for test, maybe you are testing a lot at once, or there is a time to refactor you code - instead of chat with dependency, ask it just one question :)

Comment: It's not that big, but just setting up a mock object for some Service or Repository, can easily take dozens of lines of code, compared to a two-liner in an integration test! And readability wins as well...

Comment: One line mock with JMock (and others) : Service service = context.mock(Service.class); // Isolate your tests by mostly testing one thing at a time then there's not a lot of setup to do - if it's hard to test it's telling you something about your design

Comment: I'm using PHPUnit, and that looks a bit more cumbersome, but I get your point, thanks.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this answer is completely wrong. You obviously never managed to successfully write integration tests, because a) they do let you know why they fail, and b) we can perfectly well do Test Driven Development with integration tests (the claim that "dependencies which will be required by class you are testing should be implemented before you write the test" is absurd). I know this because I actually wrote hundreds of integration tests, most of them by following the TDD process; and when they fail it's usually not a problem to find the specific cause; I have been doing this for years.

Comment: @Rogério thanks for leaving the comment :) You are judging in a maximalist  way. You obviously cannot do tdd with integration tests, because a) they are slow. have you ever been on project with 10k unit tests? how often you run them? b) you cannot run test until you have all components ready. have you worked in teams which split feature development? e.g. some guys are creating services, other guys work on ui, and you have dba to create db structure. and you suggest to go 'blind' way without any verification until all these guys will do their job? etc. do you have some examples of tests to see?

Comment: Come on, I even wrote a TDD-based integration test *today*. It was for a bug found in the app; the new test first confirmed the bug is there, then I fixed the code under test and rerun the test to see it passed. My IDE reports it takes 2s to run. Yes, 2s is "slow" by unit test standards, but it's perfectly fine for productive software development. Having a test suite with thousands of tests is irrelevant, as you don't run them all on every coding step. A Jenkins-based build server typically runs that in several minutes, which is fine for a non-interactive test run.

Comment: As for "split feature development", in my experience this is rare in real-world projects. Typically, one or more teams work from a shared SVN/Git repository. Personally, I consider it a terribly bad idea to compartmentalize development in services, UI, etc. - it's clearly a non/anti-agile approach. Having a DBA, however, is perfectly common and fine - it does not create TDD-related problems with unit *or* integration tests (I started out with automated testing in a project with a DBA, yet we developed ~3000 integration tests). Again, I sense you just lack the experience...

Comment: This answer is not correct. But good thing is you write unit tests. people skilled with unit tests need to 'graduate' to integration tests. Your skills are best used there. 1) you said split development and integration tests cannot do it. that is right. 2) you said integration tests are slow, that is right too. Why would someone still write integration tests? the answer is simple. Mocks wont catch errors. Very limited text to explain still eg: leave out UI and test API to backend full. Integration test is difficult as DB/ infra seeding is needed but unit test skills is scarce and you have it.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing wrong with it, at all. On the contrary, based on my experience I would say that it's wrong to favour unit testing. The perception your team had that tests "become faster, and cleaner" is the same I had many years ago and since then.

I would even suggest that you drop unit tests altogether, and continue investing in integration tests. I say this as someone who develops a testing library with a very sophisticated mocking API, who gave isolated unit tests the benefit of the doubt for years, and then finally came to the conclusion that integration tests (after having written many tests of both kinds) are *so* much better.

One correction, though: unit tests "in isolation & with mock objects" are *not* the "standard way". As you probably know, Kent Beck is the ["father" of TDD](https://arialdomartini.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/you-wont-believe-how-old-tdd-is) and the inventor of JUnit. But guess what, Kent did not use mocks at all in his TDD unit tests. Strictly speaking, the "unit" tests written by the guy who invented TDD are closer to *integration* tests, as they make no effort of isolating the tested unit from its dependencies. (This is a common misunderstanding about unit testing. For an accurate definition see [this article](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html) by Martin Fowler.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, the Fowler link you mentioned is interesting, especially the part about *solitary* or *sociable* tests!

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Unit testing and Integration has it's benefits. But we may not be able to find time to do both Unit test and Integration tests together. We will have to let one go. The best is to use just integration tests as it gives you better assurance on the real working of the code and also allows you to make changes fast.

These are my top recommended blogs on this

1. [Before you feed the Unit Test Beast...](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/before-you-feed-unit-test-beast-s-a-n-j-ay-mohan)
2. "Lean Testing or Why Unit Tests are Worse than You Think"
   https://medium.com/@eugenkiss/lean-testing-or-why-unit-tests-are-worse-than-you-think-b6500139a009
3. "Why You Need to Stop Writing Unit Tests" https://hackernoon.com/why-you-need-to-stop-writing-unit-tests
4. "The No. 1 unit testing best practice: Stop doing it"
   https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/no-1-unit-testing-best-practice-stop-doing-it
5. Martin Fowler *(the legend)* [tactically denying unit testing](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html) and calling integration test by a different name "*sociable tests*" (perhaps not to offend unit test pundits). Martin the legend, also gives a great advice `If you have tests that are useful, but take longer than you want the commit suite to run, then you should build a DeploymentPipeline and put the slower tests in a later stage of the pipeline.`